# Render a nested Tab screen in a Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

Seems it should be so simple but I can't figure it out. I have a nested Tab Navigator inside a Stack Navigator like so:

```
function App(){

 const Main = () =>{
   <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName={"Players"}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Players" component={FindPlayers} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Requests" component={MatchRequests} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
 }


....

return (
<NavigationContainer>
 <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Main"} >
  <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main}/>
  <Stack.Screen name="CourtPicker" component={CourtPicker}/>
 </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
)}
```

It renders a blank screen with the Header that says "Main" instead of rendering the `FindPlayers` component.

My expectation is that I've defined an initial route `Main` which should render my `Main` component which is a `Tab` navigator, which should in turn render the `Players` component because I've defined the `initialRouteName` as such.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [Nesting navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)

Try :

```
   <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}/>
```

Comment: I'm not looking to hide the header, the incorrect header is being shown right now. It renders a screen called "Main" instead of my Tab Navigator

Comment: NVM this works...although I must say that this property is headerShown is very strange and implies that it's the header that is hidden, not the entire screen. Anyway thanks!